# Silverlight - Exposing canvas within user control

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, canvas

Given a custom user control having a canvas within.

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">
        <Canvas x:Name="CanvasDropArea" Background="#FFF7BDBD"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to expose the canvas to allow other controls to be append into the above said user control?

```
<CustomControlWithCanvas>
   <Canvas>
        <!--other user control-->
   <Canvas>
</CustomControlWithCanvas>
```

I have tried exposing it as a properties but that fails, as its be treated as a normal property instead of Collection which allow UIElements to be appended. However, i was able to append controls onto the element using code behind by retrieving the canvas and adding it manually.
So what should be the correct way of exposing the canvas? to allow it be alter during design time, and retain canvas TOP and left dependency property as well.

Comment: I wonder why can't you just use a normal canvas? What's the reason that you need to put it inside a usercontrol?

Comment: what i was trying to achive is having a borders and a few custom behaviors wired up to the canvas, so instead of repeating this (8 canvas in total) i would just make it as a generic user control. so in future if i were to append additional behaviors i would only require to edit my main user control. Or is there a better way to implement this instead?

Comment: Are these behaviors attached to the `Border` or the `Canvas`?

Comment: What my user control would consist is (Border, canvas and 2 button [left and right]) the behaviors they would have are a list of mouse events, It works similar to a media player, having the mouse hover [with an object being dragged] to canvas would make the border change (into dotted), where else the 2 buttons would appear if either having being mouse enter, and hidden for mouse over.

what this would result is a group of these control being layout within a grid, allowing user to drag an object from one of these "CustomCanvas" control to another. i was thinking of wrapping it together.

Comment: I think one way to achieve this is to use a behavior, you can manually add your object into the canvas in code behind right? Just use a behaivor to encapsulate this piece of code and attach the behavior to your usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - change the type of your control from UserControl to ContentControl, put  inside of your Canvas and bind the ContentPresenter's Content property to your control's Content property somehow - perhaps by naming your control and using .

In a more standard way - you would implement it as a templated/custom control instead of a UserControl, put the template in your Themes/Generic.xaml instead of MyControl.xaml, define DefaultStyleKey in your constructor, define TemplateParts etc.